# Flyway ClassNotFoundException: JavaUtilLogCreator

Tags: java, osgi, database-migration, flyway

I'm using Flyway 5.2.4 and OSGI Bundle Activator. I want to migrate database on bundle Start() method.
Here's my ActivatorClass:

```
import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceRegistration;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private ServiceRegistration serviceRegistration;

    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) {
        log.info("Starting...");
        serviceRegistration = bundleContext.registerService(IConnector.class.getName(), new Connector(), null);
        log.info("Started.");

        //FlyWay Section
        Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure().dataSource("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/", "postgres", "12345").load();
        flyway.migrate();
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) {
        log.info("Stopping...");
        serviceRegistration.unregister();
        log.info("Stopped.");
    }

}
```

As you can see, I'm using slf4j as my Logger. Maybe that's why I get this errors in my StackTrace after app deploying:

```
java.lang.Exception: Could not start bundle mvn:internship/db-connector/1.0.0 in feature(s) feature-1.0.0: Activator start error in bundle db-connector [2343].
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.startBundle(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:519)[20:org.apache.karaf.features.core:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.installFeatures(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:474)[20:org.apache.karaf.features.core:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.installFeature(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:415)[20:org.apache.karaf.features.core:3.0.8]
        at Proxy683d032e_ad2c_4b9a_98f7_baca7b5564f1.installFeature(Unknown Source)[:]
        at Proxyfff1bf4b_671e_4ff6_bb97_e0dabf9f20e8.installFeature(Unknown Source)[:]
        at org.apache.karaf.kar.internal.KarServiceImpl.installFeatures(KarServiceImpl.java:282)[89:org.apache.karaf.kar.core:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.karaf.kar.internal.KarServiceImpl.install(KarServiceImpl.java:111)[89:org.apache.karaf.kar.core:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.karaf.kar.internal.KarServiceImpl.install(KarServiceImpl.java:93)[89:org.apache.karaf.kar.core:3.0.8]
        at Proxy40d8d25a_37b2_4855_a381_fbb78daa68ce.install(Unknown Source)[:]
        at Proxy068a2f57_120b_4ee8_b953_7c8262bae9a2.install(Unknown Source)[:]
        at org.apache.karaf.deployer.kar.KarArtifactInstaller.update(KarArtifactInstaller.java:62)[91:org.apache.karaf.deployer.kar:3.0.8]
        at Proxy3c143b4c_a2ef_49d0_870b_21a9b5f74704.update(Unknown Source)[:]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.update(DirectoryWatcher.java:1101)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.2]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.update(DirectoryWatcher.java:898)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.2]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:478)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.2]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:355)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.2]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:307)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.2]
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle db-connector [2343].
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2196)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2064)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:942)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.startBundle(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:516)[20:org.apache.karaf.features.core:3.0.8]
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.FeatureDetector.isSlf4jAvailable(FeatureDetector.java:96)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.logging.LogCreatorFactory.getLogCreator(LogCreatorFactory.java:39)
        at org.flywaydb.core.api.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:78)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.FeatureDetector.<clinit>(FeatureDetector.java:25)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.logging.LogCreatorFactory.getLogCreator(LogCreatorFactory.java:35)
        at org.flywaydb.core.api.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:78)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.<clinit>(Flyway.java:86)
        at internship.connectors.postgresConnector.Activator.start(Activator.java:18)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2146)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to instantiate class org.flywaydb.core.internal.logging.javautil.JavaUtilLogCreator : org.flywaydb.core.internal.logging.javautil.JavaUtilLogCreator
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.ClassUtils.instantiate(ClassUtils.java:63)[2348:org.flywaydb.core:5.2.4]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.logging.LogCreatorFactory.getLogCreator(LogCreatorFactory.java:46)[2348:org.flywaydb.core:5.2.4]
        at org.flywaydb.core.api.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:78)[2348:org.flywaydb.core:5.2.4]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.ClassUtils.<clinit>(ClassUtils.java:39)[2348:org.flywaydb.core:5.2.4]
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.flywaydb.core.internal.logging.javautil.JavaUtilLogCreator
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_212]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.ClassUtils.instantiate(ClassUtils.java:61)[2348:org.flywaydb.core:5.2.4]
        ... 33 more
```

So, I just have no idea what's wrong here, I've used simpliest example from official Flyway's site and get this errors.
I've already try to delete my own Logger. I thought it can let FlyWay to use it's logger, but everything goes the same way (same errors).

Could you help me?

P.S. Looks like this [pull request](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/pull/2384) somehow related to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it seems Flyway might have issues in OSGi. Maybe you can provide them an issue and your example.

Another issue with your example is that you try to access the DataSource via a url. This does not work in OSGi. The reason is that this way flyway has to have direct access to the database driver classes. This does not work in OSGi.

In OSGi the way to access a Database is with a [DataSourceFactory](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.jdbc.html) which the database driver creates as a service. From this factory you can create a DataSource.

As not all database drivers offer this service there is [pax-jdbc](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/spaces/PAXJDBC/pages/23953600/Documentation) which provides factories for all common databases. It also allows to create a DataSource including pooling from a OSGi config.

Your approach of migrating on bundle start is a very bad idea. The methods in the activator must return quickly and a databse migration might take a while. Of course you want to make sure the migration takes place before any bundle in the system accesses the database. Fortunately there is a way to hook into the DataSource creation to do things like a migration.

See the [liquibase tutorial](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/tree/master/liquibase) which also shows a database migration. It uses the PreHook offered by pax-jdbc which makes sure your [migration code](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/blob/7e62502287572eff0594c5c5a93f512b66510540/liquibase/service/src/main/java/net/lr/tutorial/db/service/Migrator.java#L31) is run before the DataSource is given to any other bundle.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, that was a bad idea to put something else in Activator. I really appreciate you for this liquibase tutorial, it's awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to avoid this error by setting a custom `LogFactory` before entering flyway's migration code. The basic idea is presented in [this sample commit](https://github.com/barryku/karaf-flyway-demo/pull/1)